# Why the extension $L/K$ is ramified in exactly those primes that divide the relative discriminant?

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L$ is the finite extension field of the number field $K$ and $p$ is a prime ideal over the ring of integer $O_K$. Then, $pO_L= \prod_{j=1}^{g} P_j^{e_j}$. By CRT, we have $$ O_L/pO_L=\prod_{j=1}^{g} O_L/P_j^{e_j}.$$
**My question:**

Why the extension $L/K$ is ramified in exactly those primes that divide the relative **discriminant** ?

How does this imply that the extension $L/K$ is unramified in all but finitely many prime ideals ?

**Updated:**

Yes I got proof of first question.

But what about the 2nd question?

**My approach for 2nd question:**

Since only finitely many prime ideals $P_j$ divide the discriminant in the above product, the extension $L/K$ ramifies only at finitely many primes. All others primes do not ramify in the extension.

Is it true ?

Comment: What is relative discriminant?

Comment: Are you following any book or lecture notes? Your questions tend to be very straightforward and can be answered if you just followed any basic text on algebraic number theory.

Comment: @Yes, I got the first proof but how to answer the 2nd question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know the unique factorization in prime ideals then $P O_L = \prod_j Q_j^{e_j} $

For each $j, O_L/Q_j$ is a finite field, let $a_j$ a generator of its multiplicative group, then $O_L/Q_j = O_K[a_j]/(Q_j \cap O_K[a_j])$.

(CRT) The $Q_j$ are distinct maximal ideals so there is some element which is $\equiv 1 \bmod Q_j$  and $\equiv 0 \bmod Q_i$ for $i \ne j$, which means you can construct some $a \in O_L$ which is $\equiv a_j \bmod Q_j$ for all $j$. Moreover we can construct it such that $L = K(a)$.

Let $f \in O_K[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $a$ so that we now consider $O_K[a] = O_K(x]/(f)$, a $O_K$-monogenic subring having all the $O_L/Q_j$ in its quotients.

> Then $\forall j, e_j=1$ iff $f$ is separable $\bmod P$ iff $Disc(f) \not \in P$

(where $Disc(\prod_l (x-b_l))= \prod_{l\ne m} (b_l-b_m)$)

Proof : the factorization of $f \bmod P$ gives all the maximal ideals of $O_K[x]/(f)$ above $P$ and the degree of the irreducible factors tell the dimension of $O_K[x]/(f)/m$ as $O_K/P$ vector space, if all the $e_j=1$ then $O_L/P \cong \prod_j O_L/Q_j$ so if unramified the dimensions must sum to $\dim(O_L/P)=\deg(f)$.

Only finitely many prime ideals of $O_K$ contain $Disc(f)$, all the others are unramified in $O_K[a]$ thus in $O_L$.

The relative discriminant of $O_L/O_K$ is the ideal generated by all the $Disc(f)$ for each minimal polynomial $f$ of some $a \in O_L$ such that $L = K(a)$.

Being an ideal of $O_K$ only finitely many primes of $O_K$ contain it (and are ramified), the others are unramified in $O_L$.

Comment: thank you for effort. Specially the 2nd answer is very helpful to me

Comment: Note it is much more complicated to understand the multiplicity of the prime ideal factors of the relative discriminant (this is the theory of the different ideal)

Comment: @renus, yes i am reading now $\text{different ideal and discriminant ideal}$.